# Boost multi_index: retrieve unique values of a non-unique key

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multi-index

I have a `boost::multi_index_container` whose elements are structs like this:

```
struct Elem {
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
};
```

The main key (in a database sense) is a `composite_key` of `a` and `b`. Other 
keys exist to perform various types of queries.

I now need to retrieve a set of all different values of `c`. These values are 
by all means *not* unique, but iterating through all entries (albeit ordered), 
or using `std::unique` seems quite a waste, considering that 
the number of different values of `c` is expected to be << than the total 
number of entries (say, 10 to 1000).

Am I missing a simple way to obtain this result more efficiently?

Comment: Are you willing to waste some extra memory in order to speed up the enumeration of c values?

Comment: Are you using an `ordered_non_unique` index for C in order to allow `std::unique` to traverse sorted C values?

Answer (score 1):

I scoured the Boost.MultiIndex documentation and can't seem to find a way to do what you want. I'm interested in knowing if it's doable.

Perhaps the best you can do is maintain a `std::map<C, size_t>` (or hash map) alongside your `multi_index_container` and keep them both "synchronized".

The map associates a C value with its occurrence count (frequency). It's essentially a histogram of C values. Each time you add an `Elem` to your `multi_index_container`, you increment the corresponding frequency in the histogram. When you remove an `Elem` from your `multi_index_counter`, you decrement the corresponding frequency in the histogram. When the frequency reaches zero, you delete that entry from the histogram.

To retrieve the set of distinct C values, you simply iterate through the `<key,value>` pairs in the histogram and look at the `key` part of each pair. If you used a `std::map`, then the distinct C values will come out sorted.

If you're going to examine the set of distinct C values only once (or rarely) then the approach I described above may be overkill. A simpler approach would be to insert all C values into a `std::set<C>` and then iterate through the set to retrieve the distinct C values.

You said that the set of distinct C's is much smaller then the total number of C's. The `std::set<C>` approach should therefore waste much less space than copying the C's to a `std::vector`, sorting the vector, then running `std::unique`.

Let's compare the time complexity of copying to a set versus copying to a vector, sorting, then running `unique`. Let N be the total number of C values, and let M be the number of distinct C values. The set approach, by my reckoning, should have a time complexity of O(N*log(M)). Since M is small and does not grow much with higher N's, the complexity effectively becomes O(N). The sorting+unique technique, on the other hand, should have a time complexity of O(N*log(N)).

Answer (score 1):

The approach I took to solving this problem was to use boost range adaptors as follows

```
const auto& indexedContainer = container.get<IndexType>();
const auto uniqueIndexRange = indexedContainer 
    | boost::adaptors::transformed([&](auto&& v) {
        return indexedContainer.key_extractor()(v); })
    | boost::adaptors::uniqued;
```